# Page Admin - Graph Api Comment as User

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

its a bit complicated because i dont understand might be a bug. 
OR MAYBE i making a mistake.

User allows the Application and the same time user ist the Admin of the Fanpage. 
I store all Data Accesstoken uid etc.. in the Database.

Now i want to post comments on a Photo as the user (The user is also Admin of the Fanpage)

The problem is that the comment is posted Successfully but the Comment is from Fanpage.

I just want to post as the user as he is.
Im using the Access Token of the User which i stored in the Database and also using Form fields with name & id.

Anybody out there facing the same problems ?

```
$details = array( 'message'=> $photodata,'access_token' => $tok, 'from' => $from);
$from = array( 'name'=> $nome,'id' => $ad);
$addscomment = $facebook->api("".$photoid."/comments", 'post', $details);
```

Comment: Please show the code that you use to post comment.

Comment: Maybe the user was logged as a pagetab. So, the acess token that do you have is for the Pagetab User.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

it's will show you have user are in the acess token.